# DIV is centered fine in Chrome/Firefox but not Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/sBKk4/

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and have built the page and everything looks correct in Chrome. But the bottom div which the code is provided above, when viewed in Safari is not center aligned.

[image: What the browser renders]

--UPDATE--

Ok, I think ive narrowed it down to the `width` css property with is different from Chrome to Safari for some reason?

Ive wrapped the whole thing in a div called `paraWrapper`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sBKk4/

The above code will display fine in Chrome but be out of place on Safari..

If I change the width however to something like `720px` then it'll look fine in Safari but be out of place in Chrome..

So I guess my question at this point is. Does anyone know why this difference would be?

I guess I can get around this by using CSS hacks but if I can fix my code for a more permanent fix that that would be great!

Comment: sorry, I meant the bottom div of the page. The one with the three elements in it which the code is in the jsfiddle link.

Comment: then u have to go give the code

Comment: ?

The code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/rzSFa/

Comment: have you tried playing around within the Developer Tools console? (alt +cmd+i)...

Comment: Works fine for me in Safari 5.1.5, windows' version (see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MPf8H.png)). What version are you using?

Comment: Ive updated the first post. I think the issue is with the width property in Safari which I can get around by using css hacks but a more pernament and cleaner solution would be great :)

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.1.2.. time to upgrade!

Comment: Thats not the entire code of the page, is it?

Comment: @ DRP96 - No, here is all the CSS but only the HTML div that is not centering in Safari - http://jsfiddle.net/sBKk4/

Comment: Your posting should contain all of the relevant code.  jsFiddle is not for _showing_ us your code, it's for demonstrating the functionality.  Someday the links will be dead and this question will be useless to future readers.

Comment: You keep saying there is something wrong with CSS `width` in Safari.  This is highly unlikely as it's one of the most widely used CSS properties... a bug in `width` would be such a huge deal and fixed quickly.  What you're seeing is a symptom caused by something else.

Comment: Your buttons are 150px wide plus padding and borders.  Their container is only 140px wide and clearly the overflow can be seen in the DOM inspector.  It's likely all this is being caused by differences in how the two browsers are rendering these buttons.

Comment: My code is massibly long. It wont allow my to post it all here as it contains external javascrit that wont load.

That is why  posted it externaly. Aswell as not to appear to spam.

Comment: @Keva161 is the width of your `paraWrapper` container imperative? You can easily replace that with a `span*` div provided by the grid and use that instead, that should work across browsers because it was meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using rows, you should use [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

remember to use a div with class row, and in there divs with spanX classes, where this Xs of all spans sums 12

and don't use the center attribute. Bootstrap makes that for you. Look at the code from [this examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you having a compatibly issue, be sure to specify your margin and padding of your div's, even if it's 0.

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```